# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Почему ошибка "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" ?

```
ALTER TABLE `_users` 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `U_test` UNIQUE (`name`, `email`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_test` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `_sessions` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  MODIFY `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE всех таблиц - в студию. Текст ошибки - полностью, от первого до последнего символа.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `_sessions` 
(
  `id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_adress` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `_users` 
(
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; ```

Comment: Найдите ссылку "Править" под вопросом и внесите изменения в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Akina #1005 - Невозможно создать таблицу `id19927414_web`.`_users` (ошибка: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 0):

Если рассмотреть создание таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE `_sessions` (`id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
  ,`user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
  ,`ip_adress` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,`created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ,`updated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL 
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  
CREATE TABLE `_users`  (`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  ,`name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
  ,`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,`created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ,`updated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

и далее, создание ограничений

```
ALTER TABLE `_users` 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `U_test` UNIQUE (`name`, `email`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_test` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `_sessions` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  MODIFY `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

то можно увидеть

1. не совместимость модифицированного поля _users(id) - BIGINT и ссылочного поля _sessions(user_id) - BIGINT UNSIGNED.
2. для Constraint references нужно, что бы был соответствующий индекс

Тогда

```
create index idx_users_id on  `_sessions` (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `_users` 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `U_test` UNIQUE (`name`, `email`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_test` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `_sessions` (`user_id`)
       ON DELETE CASCADE,
  MODIFY `id` BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ;
```

Но по смыслу, ограничение должно быть в другую сторону. Т.е. user_id в _sessions должен ссылаться на id в _users

```
ALTER TABLE `_users` 
  MODIFY `id` BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 ,ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ,ADD CONSTRAINT `U_test` UNIQUE (`name`, `email`)
  ;

ALTER TABLE `_sessions` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_test` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `_users` (`id`) 
              ON DELETE CASCADE
  ;
```

Comment: Перезаписал FK_test в _sessions как в вашем примере, ошибка всё ещё есть

Comment: И какая ошибка? На какой строке? Какая версия СУБД? Создан ли индекс?

Comment: Ошибка была в том что я записал в файл ALTER TABLE `_sessions`  выше  ALTER TABLE `_users`. Спасибо за помощь.